# How to handle Zeros in dependent variable in Multiple Linear regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, zero-inflation

I am totally new to machine learning (and to this platform too) and was trying to implement Multiple linear Regression  to improve my ranking algorithm.

I have a data-set which have the following variables

- Category of the product ( Independent variable)
- Price of the product (Independent variable)
- Product sold in last N days (Independent variable)
- Position of the product in the list (Independent variable)
- CTR ( Clicks to Views ratio) (**Dependent Variable**)

The data-set contains more than 1 million rows , out of which only 30,000 contains **non zero** value while the rest of them contains zero value. When plotting for "Non Zero CTR" data-set , I get proper Fitted vs Residual graph and Normal Q-Q graph. But when I plot the complete data-set ( including zero CTR values) , The graphs get distorted and the results are too skewed.

I have researched about Negative Binomial Regression (NBR) and Zero-inflated Negative Binomial Regression (ZINB) , but they work with counts.

To summarize, I have more than 97% zeros in dependent variable which is skewing my results.

Suggestion and help is requested.

EDIT -
The sample data-frame is below

```
catalog_date <- data.frame (

sku=c("UB306GT3332700,"UB306GT3332700","TE577HC3218889","TE577HC3218889","TE577HC3218889","TE577HC3218889","TA842WT2467075","TA842WT2466909","ST695PA2466907","SI270VC3218918","SI270VC3218918","SI270VC3218918","SI270VC3218918","SI270VC3218918","SI270VC3218918","SI270PA3218912","SI270PA3218912","SI270PA3218912","SI270HA3218921","SI270HA3218921")

category = c("gaming_titles","gaming_titles","health_care_accessories","health_care_accessories","health_care_accessories","health_care_accessories","gift_sets_and_combos","gift_sets_and_combos","hair_stylers","vacuum_cleaners","vacuum_cleaners","vacuum_cleaners","vacuum_cleaners","vacuum_cleaners","vacuum_cleaners","hair_dryers","hair_dryers","hair_dryers","mixer_juicer_grinders","mixer_juicer_grinders"
)

price = c(171,171,240,240,240,240,222,280,79,135,135,135,135,135,135,108,108,108,290,290)

sales = c(0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1)

Position = c(15,7,3,6,1,2,1,1,0,1,17,2,38,45,7,12,47,8,3,1)

Clicks = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

Views = c(3,3,2,6,7,2,2,2,0,3,7,3,2,2,3,7,2,3,15,3)

CTR = c(0,0,0.5,0.1667,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0667,0)


)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to get rid of observations containing zeros and apply your algorithm on rest of records? It would be better if you can share part of your data `dput(head(df, 20))` with question.

Comment: You should do everything you can to avoid a ratio as dependent variable in regression. I strongly suggest you use Clicks as DV and use Views as independent variable.

Comment: @Roland , will try to do the same but the problem of zero will remain there

Comment: But then you have a (possibly zero-inflated) count variable which is much easier to model.